# Sdk Java API for creating dashboard

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Do SDK Java API support creating dashboards ;widget and adding graphs to widgets in cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, CloudWatch does not support creating or managing dashboards through an API.

Answer (score 0):

It does now. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html .

We wrote a Lambda to query our CloudFormation stacks periodically and generate/update CloudWatch Dashboards dynamically. Works like a charm.